# MediaRecorder not recording audio

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

I am tried to record audio using MediaRecorder:

```
MediaRecorder recorder= new MediaRecorder();
recorder.reset();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);//
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.setMaxDuration(30*60*1000);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Code works fine no exception occur at run time, some times file not created on SDCard if file will create then file size is 0KB.

I have also register Error and Info listeners `OnInfoListener` `OnErrorListener` in
`OnInfoListener public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra)` returns what=802 and extra=6
I have tried this code on real device but not works.

Comment: Try removing the reset line.

Comment: I have tried removing the reset line, but problem remain same.

Comment: Did you end up finding out what was causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("start", "prepare() failed");
                }

                mRecorder.start();
```

if you getting any error then please paste logcat.

Comment: first step you can find your file in sd card?

Comment: If I tried to record audio 10 times then out of 10 attempts two times file created in sd card but eigth times file is not created in sd card.

Comment: Browser shows "Server not found" error for [pastebin.com/X27pg7Ys](http://pastebin.com/X27pg7Ys)

Comment: It could mean the device has no microphone.. perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent reference for MediaRecorder to capture media.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

The sample code used in the tutorial works without any changes.
(Just make sure you added the necessary permissions in the manifest file)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.